Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Suddenly Extremely Slow
I've got a MS Surface Book running Ubuntu 22.04, that's been running perfectly fine for at least a year. Yesterday, I opened it and found that it had an unexplained reboot. When I logged in, I noticed that it was suddently excruciatingly slow - even with the login. The mouse moves around just fine wiht no lag, but any keyboard input is lagged by a few seconds. Opening / switching programs is also very slow to respond. I'm only runnng system monitor, chromium, and joplin (none of this is new). Same slow performance when neither chromium or joplin are running.
I have livepatch on, and have performed apt-get update & upgrade.
I've checked df, and have more than 30 GB available disk space on /dev/nvme0n1p5; htop and system monitor show my 4 CPUs are generally staying below 50% usage, memory usage is about 6 GB of 16.7GB, and no swap space is being used.
I don't see anything that could be causing this bad performance, and have no idea how to debug this. Can someone help? Thanks.
Update 1: I checked for journal errors and found several related to multimode-indicator, which I see is not supported on my version, so removed it. That improved the situation, but not fully. Checking for more errors, there's a lot of SQLite errors related to bijiben and bijiben-shell-s, but I can't figure out what this is. Any suggestions?
Update 2: I have removed bijiben and multiload-indicator, but the performance issues continue. I've dug into this more, as best I could, and identified that the usage of all 4 CPUs approaches and even stays at 100% whenever I'm doing something online. I have observed this with both Chromium or Firefox. I see the same behavior, though not as extreme when I synchronize with my Joplin cloud. My system monitor shows this, right after I refreshed a new tab in Chromium. The journal is not showing excessive or consistent errors. I observe the same behavior while connected to different wifi networks. Any ideas? Thanks.


Have you checked the system monitor to see if anything is eating up process?  Or, have you checked your swap -- maybe memory is eaten up by something and you're swapping out a lot.  Check out this sample image https://i.sstatic.net/fzvLAmY6.png  which shows process and swap amount.  Check yours and post back.

I already indicated that I checked these items and nothing looks amiss.

Check your processor frequency, if windows is installed you can run Surface Diagnostic Toolkit to eliminate hardware issues and see if your fan is is working.

Use journalctl -b | grep -i error to check for any errors that might point to something slowing your system down and use something like sudo htop or sudo iotop to check for stuff like disk activity when you are experiencing the issue.

Thanks mchid. I looked at the errors, and there was a frequent one that referenced multiload-indicator, which I indeed had running in the statusbar. Disabling it seems to have solved the issue. It's unfortunate; I really found that useful, and apt can't find the gnome extension manager to install tophat as a replacement.

Thanks for your help all. I've updated the question, with a query about more errors related to "bijiben", which I can't figure out what is.

apt show bijiben  indicates this is a gnome3 note editor.
